# How can liferay server cluster using one shared lucene index on a mounted volume?

Tags: java, lucene, liferay, cluster-computing

I have a liferay cluster(2 servers), while each liferay boundle has one lucene files, I want to separate these lucene files into a mounted volume, like EFS. Is there any way that I can do this? I had tried, but failed, the main reason is that the server will lock the lucene file when indexing, and another server can not access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a clustered environment, it is recommended to not use a plain file base lucene search index. Liferay rather recommends ([Liferay Clustering](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/liferay-clustering)) to use a pluggable enterprise search such as SOLR or Elasticsearch. There are also some help advices on that page for setup such an environment.

Comment: Thanks, @Andre Albert

Answer (score 0):

As Liferay says:

> Sharing a Search Index (not recommended unless you have a file
>   locking-aware SAN)

That's why, the best option are:

1. Use pluggable engines like [SolR](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/36322550) or ElasticSearch ([Elasticray](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/41044606) or others).
2. Configure Liferay cluster with 1 node writer and 1 node reader with the property:

   > index.read.only=false

IMHO, I would try to use elasticsearch for indexes because it's the one used in the last versions (7+) and Lucene is not as powerful as Elastic, for example with the performance.